# D3 - nest.entries() throws Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I've tried to purloin Mike's [excellent stacked area chart](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3020685) by replacing it with my own data, and all hell has broken loose in a way I don't usually encounter at this level of example adaptation. Specifically, it throws this at the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

That's in reference to the fairly innocuous line that implements the stack function:

```
var layers = stack(nest.entries(data));
```

My data schema is matched almost exactly with that of the example - the one difference being that "date" has a 4-digit year, but I've accounted for that with

```
d3.time.format("%m/%d/%Y");
```

I can't figure out why 'nest.entries(data)' is coming up as undefined, or even why the stack function is asking for a property called "1". Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Attempted chart here: http://bl.ocks.org/wboykinm/10499388

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the same date represented for each group, like this:

```
date,key,value
1/4/2013,phone,549
1/4/2013,email,402
1/4/2013,url,620
8/4/2013,phone,165
8/4/2013,email,265
8/4/2013,url,52
15/4/2013,phone,300
15/4/2013,email,145
15/4/2013,url,450
...
```

Comment: Oh, I totally don't; that's a good point. The data is actually variable from group to group. I could probably standardize it by week, but do I understand correctly that a stacked chart will always require  x-axis values to line up between groups?

Comment: Pretty much, sometimes you see it organized it like this: `1/4/2013,549,402,620`, where the columns would represent `date,phone,email,url`. Check this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1134768), using date as the grouping variable.

Comment: One nuance about the x-axis...not always because you might want a horizontal bar chart, like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/datashaman/rBfy5/2/)...but you get the idea of having to group along an axis.